# Why the following will produce segmentation fault?

Tags: c, constants, segmentation-fault

```
int main()
{
        char *temp = "Paras";

        int i;
        i=0;

        temp[3]='F';

        for (i =0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
                printf("%c\n", temp[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

Why  `temp[3]='F';` will cause segmentation fault since `temp` is not `const`?

Comment: Because your C/OS implementation is generous and immediately terminating the program when you invoke undefined behavior rather than conjuring demonic forces upon your nose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not allowed to modify string literals.

Comment: Yeah. And I think compilers should warn you about that, but gcc, for example, doesn't. Either way, the standard allows the compiler to put string constants into read only memory.

Comment: @cse `char *temp = "Paras"` means `temp` is pointing to a string literal. Attempting to modify a string literal is undefined. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR30-C.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals `char temp[6] = "Paras";` does something completely different - it creates an array (not a pointer, and not constant) and **copies** the string literal into that array.

Answer (score 0):

*temp is defined as a pointer to a constant (sometimes called a string literal - especially in other languages).

Therefore the line with the error is trying to change the third character of this constant.

Try defining a char array and using strcpy to copy temp into it. Then do the above code on the array, it should work. (sorry my ipad here doesn't like to insert code into SO's interface)

Comment: I know the feeling. I think SO developers should consider iPad users for the forseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, `temp` is a pointer, which points to a random address where the nameless array with the value `Paras` resides. And that array is a string constant.

For your program to work, you need to use an array instead of a pointer:

```
char temp[6] = "Paras";
```

Now if you're wondering why it's `temp[6]` instead of `temp[5]`, the above code initializes a string, and completely different from:

```
char temp[5] = {'P', 'a', 'r', 'a', 's'};
```

Strings are terminated with a null terminator `\0`. And the string initialization will be like:

```
char temp[6] = {'P', 'a', 'r', 'a', 's', '\0'};
```

Comment: Better still, `char temp[] = `, so the compiler figures out the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
  temp[3]='F';
```

This line is not correct.The "temp" is const value,So you can't modify it.